# Is there a way to input different value for the same data when the same function is called multiple times?

Tags: c++

I'm creating a student data management program in C++ and the function to insert examination marks is buggy.

The code given below is enough to recreate the buggy part of the program.

- I have tried to increase the size of `sub[]` to 16
- I have tried to insert data one after the other instead of a loop

None of the above seem to solve the problem

Menu function:

```
char ch;
main_menu:
clrscr();
cout << "Press the key for your choice:\n";
cout << "D -> Edit details\n";
cout << "R -> Get result\n";
cout << "I -> Insert marks\n";
cout << "E -> Exit Program";

choice:
ch = getch();
switch(ch)
{
case 'd':   
    //edit_nam();           Ignore this one
    goto main_menu;
    break;

case 'i':
    ins_mar();
    goto main_menu;
    break;

case 'r':
    //get_res();           This one is not related to the problem
    goto main_menu;
    break;

case 'e':
    break;

default:
        goto choice;
}
```

Insert marks function:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
clrscr();
cout << "Enter details of subject:" << i + 1;
cout << "\nSubject name:";
cout << "\nMarks:";
gotoxy(14, 1);
cin.getline(student.marks[i].sub, 8);
gotoxy(7,2);
cin >> student.marks[i].mark;

(i != 5) ? cout << "\nPress any key to continue..." : cout << "\nPress any key to return to menu...";
getch();
}
```

Student structure:

```
struct stu
{
    char name[20];
int ID;
int cls;
mar marks[6];
};
```

Marks structure:

```
struct mar
{
    char sub[8];
    float mark;
}
```

If the code was working fine, then it would ask the user to enter the marks for all six subjects, every time the function is called in one run.

However, It is not so. In the first time of function call, everything happens in the correct manner, but it does not ask for subject name after first subject in any of the other runs.

Comment: Have you used your debugger to walk through your program and investigate what's going on?

Comment: What is the input you give the program? What is the expected output from that input? What is the actual output? Please take some time to ead about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And if possible, please try to create proper [mcve] that we can actually copy and try for ourselves.

Comment: Don't mix `getch` with `std::cin`.  Read strings into `std::string`, not char arrays.  Unless you want to handle overflow / discarding excess characters from the stream yourself.  Almost always it's best to use `std::getline` when asking the user for any input at all.  Feel free to parse that with `std::istringstream` afterwards.

Comment: On a more stylistic note, don't use labels and `goto` instead of loop. Use actual loops. Even if you need to add more logic, loops are better in the long run for the maintainability of your programs.

Comment: A `goto` does have its place.  But in my 40 years of programming in C and then C++, I've found a `goto` to be the right choice twice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Include iostream, conio, stdlib, and then call menu in main

That will run the program

Comment: When I bolt together random bits of code to make an MCVE to test I almost always wind up accidentally fixing the bug or exposing a different bug. Doesn't do much good, so I'm going to pass on answering this question and see about answering a question that is well posed.

Comment: @DarshK I suggest remove `clrscr` in your code, it not only clear the screen but also clean up the problem.